# UICollectionView view and constraints to make cells fit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, interface-builder

After playing a bit these days with `UICollectionView`, I think I understand how it works but, there's something I'm missing.

I have 8 views added to the `UICollectionView` and they do not jump to the next row when they don't fit in the screen. It seems that the `UICollectionView` is bigger than the screen. I had to use constraints on the `UICollectionView` to make it same width and height of the parent view.

Here some screenshots:

Without Constraints:

[image: Without constraints:]

With Constraints:

[image: With constraints]

Could anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't set constraints on a view in Storyboard, it will retain its dimensions as specified in the Storyboard - it will not automatically resize with `superview`. So the fact that the root view of `UIViewCntroller` was resized to fit the screen does not affect size of `UICollectionView`.

As you have been creating your `UICollectionView` in universal size it ended up much bigger that actual screen.

---

To answer your follow-up questions in the comments:

1. At the runtime will persist constants of it's width and height, not relation to the size of it's parent (Unless you specify otherwise).
2. When `UIViewController` is shown, (in most cases) it's root view is resized to fit the screen. However, it's children will remain unchanged, unless you specify otherwise.
3. By universal size I meant the size of `UIViewController` in the storyboard as you specify in `Attribute Inspector -> Size -> Freeform`, which defaults to `600x600`. I suppose "freeform" would be more correct than "universal".

Comment: I'm a bit lost here. 1) I see how UIViewCollection fits the parent view  in the storyboard. So, won't this be its size at runtime? 2) Why the UIViewCollection parent view is resized to the screen size without constraints but the UICollectionView doesn't? 3) What do you mean by universal size? Sorry if this are dumb questions but I'm pretty new to all this :)

Comment: So, I must always use constraints when using a UICollectionView to make the UICollectionView be same parent size? It's odd apple did not implemented this as the default behaviour don't you think?

Comment: Well you can add `UICollectionViewController` to the storyboard, which has `UICollectionView` as a root view, and thus will resize it automatically.